# Perl - Capture:Tiny and threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am experimenting with different ways of capturing standard output/errors from the child process. My current solution uses open3. It works in most cases, but in some scenarios it causes deadlock, especially often it happens on Windows for some reason. I am trying to replace it with Capture::Tiny. It does not seem to have this deadlock issue, but there is another problem. It does not work well with threads. And I need to run child processes from threads. Output from the main thread gets re-directed and merged with output of the child process started from another thread. Documentation says:

> Filehandles are global. Mixing up I/O and captures in different threads without coordination is going to cause problems.

I could not find any details on that 'coordination' thing. Perhaps somebody could explain, what kind of coordination can be applied here?
Below is a simplified example, which demonstrates the problem:

```
##### test.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Capture::Tiny qw(:all);
use Data::Dumper;

sub RunCmd
{
    my ($cmdArr) = @_;
    my $exe = shift @$cmdArr;
    my $tid = threads->tid();
    open my $outFh, "+>out_$tid.tmp" or die "Cannot open tmp out: $!";
    open my $errFh, "+>err_$tid.tmp" or die "Cannot open tmp err: $!";
    my ($out, $err, $exitCode) = capture { system($exe, @$cmdArr); } stdout => $outFh, stderr => $errFh;
    close $outFh;
    close $errFh;
    $exitCode = $exitCode >> 8;
    return ($exitCode == 0 ? 1 : 0, [ split(/(?<=\n)/, $out) ], [ split(/(?<=\n)/, $err) ], $exitCode);
}

sub StartJob
{
    my ($job) = @_;
    my($ret, $out, $err, $exitCode) = RunCmd($job->{'cmd'});
    $job->{'ret'} = $ret;
    $job->{'out'} = $out;
    $job->{'err'} = $err;
    $job->{'exitCode'} = $exitCode;
    return $job;
}

sub Execute
{
    my ($cmdList) = @_;
    my @threads = ();
    foreach (@$cmdList)
    {
        my $job = { 'cmd' => $_ };
        my $t = threads->new(sub { return StartJob($job) });
        push @threads, $t;
    }
    my @output = ();
    foreach my $t (@threads)
    {
        my $result = $t->join();
        push @output, $result;
    }
    return \@output;
}

my $commands = [
    [ $^X, 'myScript.pl', 'command1' ],
    [ $^X, 'myScript.pl', 'command2' ]
];

my $output = Execute($commands);
print Dumper($output);             # this output goes to out_1.tmp file
##### end of test.pl


##### myScript.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd = $ARGV[0] // 'UNDEF';
foreach (1..5)
{
    sleep 1;
    print "$cmd: $_\n";
}

$cmd eq 'command2' and print STDERR "Error in $cmd\n"; 
##### end of myScript.pl
```

Comment: A far less issue prone and more efficient method to accomplish this would be using something like [IO::Async::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Process).

Comment: Capture::Tiny necessarily changes *the process's* STDERR